# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTING function

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @FileNumber int

Set @FileNumber = cast (SubString(@fileName, CharIndex('Stats', @fileName) + 6, charindex('.',@fileName) - (CharIndex('Stats', @fileName) + 6)) as int)
```

I'm passing in `''` for the `@fileName` and getting this error. This is in SQL Server 2016

Comment: what data you have. Can you share few rows. You might need to add a case statement as there must be a -ve value passing to the left function.

Answer (score 2):

Because ...

```
select SubString('',  6 , - 6)
```

Returnes ...

```
Msg 536, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql